# Проблема с отображением звездного рейтинга WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго дня!

Помогите разобраться. Криво отображается звездный рейтинг на странице товара. 
Пытался менять стили, подключал FontAwesome, все бесполезно.

Может кто сталкивался...

```
star-rating {
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    he‌​ight:1em;
    line-height‌​:1;
    font-size:1em;
    wid‌​th:5.4em;
    font-family‌​:star
}

.woocommerce .star-rating::before {
    content:'\73\73\73\73\73';
    color:#d3ced2‌​;
    float:left;
    top:0;
    le‌​ft:0;
    position:absolu‌​te
}
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Приложите css-код в вопрос в виде текста

Comment: CSS стандартный WooCommerce. Стили не менял:
star-rating{
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
height:1em;
line-height:1;
font-size:1em;
width:5.4em;
font-family:star}
.star-rating::before{
content:'\73\73\73\73\73';
color:#d3ced2;
float:left;
top:0;
left:0;
position:absolute}

Comment: У вас на картинке стиль обведён в красную рамку. Его надо приложить к вопросу в виде текста

Comment: star-rating::before{content:'\73\73\73\73\73';color:#d3ced2;float:left;top:0;left:0;position:absolute}
star-rating span::before{content:'\53\53\53\53\53';top:0;position:absolute;left:0}

Comment: а в чем проблема ? в том, что $ и звезда накладываются? ну и поставьте одну из span display: none;

Comment: Да,я так делал, но там звезды должны быть закрашенными

Comment: Они будут закрашенными, когда рейтинг будет на нужном уровне

Answer (score 0):

Решение следующее:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating span::before {
    font-family:Star!important;
}

.woocommerce .star-rating::before {
    font-family:Star!important;
}
```